# How to create a conan-centre and bintray/bincrafters offline repository in an airgapped system?

Tags: repository, offline, bintray, conan

How to download entire conan-center and bintray packages to put in a central server of an organisation which has air gapped LAN?

I do not understand where to start? Can conan download recipes recursively?

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to download the complete ConanCenter, it is just too big to be downloaded (several hundreds of packages, with a few versions each, and each version can contain up to 100 different binaries).

You can run your own Artifactory (https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/uploading_packages/artifactory_ce.html), the CE edition is completely free. You could install the packages that you need first from ConanCenter, to a computer. Then plug that computer in your LAN, configure the remote to point to that Artifactory CE, and upload everything.

If you have such security requirements, I would probably recommend forking the https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index repository, and building the binaries yourself, in your own computers and platforms, then upload them to your LAN Artifactory. In that way you have complete control over your binaries, can re-build at will if necessary too.

Comment: I have unlimited data and unlimited storage. This is for making an air gapped repository in my company.

Comment: Sure, with your Artifactory CE in your isolated network, you can get it. The question is how to populate that server from packages from the outside. For that level of isolation, I wouldn't recommend getting binaries from the outside world, but building them yourself, from a fork of the conan-center-index repo. This is common practice and a majority of Conan users do that.

Comment: How to do that? I have never used Conan. Can you give me an idea?

Comment: The docs are pretty comprehensive, I suggest starting it from the beginning https://docs.conan.io, for a quick check how to upload packages to Artifactory, can go to: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/uploading_packages/artifactory_ce.html